# Using jQuery to able/disable RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable some RequiredFieldValudators on this way:

```
var emailEmpty = $("#registerContent").find("[id$=email_blank]");  
company.click(function () {
    ValidatorEnable(emailEmpty, false);  
});
```

I've read a lot about how to able/disable validators and it seems as simple as type  ValidatorEnable(yourValidator, false) but that isn't working for me, because the ErrorMessage still fire. Where is my mistake?? Ty.

Comment: What is the error? where is the rest of the JavaScript/Jquery code? do you have a reference to JQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var $id= $('[id$=email_blank]');

var emailEmpty = $("#registerContent").find($id);  
company.click(function () {
    ValidatorEnable(emailEmpty, false);  
});
```

Comment: I've just tryed it, but the mistake isn't in if I'm getting correctly the RequiredFieldValidator's ID or not. I made sure that I'm getting it in the correctly way, because I tryed this: emailEmpty.hide() and it worked perfect because the RequiredFieldValidator disappeared. So the mistake is on ValidatorEnable, I don't know why... Ty anyway